Synced audio in sequencer with
Noob here using blender 4.1, very frustrated at something which feels like it should be simple.
I want to animate a scene in sync with a voice recording, so that for ex I can animate a lightbulb to appear when I say "lightbulb".
I imported the audio into the sequencer, and am keyframing in playback. I can see that when I scrub through in playback, it also scrubs through in the sequencer (and vice-versa) -- it looks like it's synced.
But, it isn't ACTUALLY in sync, and something is wrong with the audio channel...
Say I've played the audio from the start, and I hear the word "lightbulb" at frame 140 in playback / 00:05+20 in sequencer.
Now, if I scrub around randomly and scrub BACK to that point -- frame 140 in playback / 00:05+20 in sequencer -- the audio is lagging behind by a few seconds.
This also happens when I pause and play -- I pause at frame 140 / 00:05+20, when I hear "lightbulb", and I keyframe my lightbulb to appear. When I press play, expecting the audio to pick up from where I paused it at, it plays it as if it's lagging a few moments behind!
This means that in order to be certain that I'm keyframing in the right objects at the right moments, I constantly need to scrub back to ZERO and let it play from the very start, listening to it all over again, or else I will be out of sync by a few seconds.
What am I doing wrong? What have I missed? Please help!

In the Playback menu, have you set Sync to the default Play Every Frame or something else like Frame Dropping or Sync to Audio? If not, does it change anything to the better when switching modes?

Woww had not seen that, I had selected sync visible audio in the sequencer, but not sync to audio in the playback... after doing that now it seems to be working as I want it to. Thank you !!

You're welcome... I wrote a proper answer you could accept, so that the question gets displayed as solved.

In the Playback menu of the Timeline, set the Sync option from the default Play Every Frame to Sync to Audio. This should fix or at least improve it.


@SkyeBD I hope this helped. If so, please consider accepting the answer.

sorry for accepting your answer so late I just saw the comments on my other post, did not know accepting answers was a thing!
